# Entity Framework duplication rows (C#)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my system, I testing some DAO classes and I found a bug. When I get an object from my database and use to other object, the EF duplicate my record.

My main code:

```
        try
        {
            UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
            BugDAO bugDAO = new BugDAO();
            TipoStatusDAO tipoStatusDAO = new TipoStatusDAO();

            Usuario usuario = usuarioDAO.GetByID(1, true);

            TipoStatus tipoStatus = tipoStatusDAO.GetByID(1, true);

            Bug bug1 = new Bug()
            {
                TipoStatus = tipoStatus,
                Descricao = "Erro ao salvar dados",
                DtAbertura = DateTime.Now,
                Usuario = usuario
            };

            bugDAO.Add(bug1);

            bugDAO.SaveChanges();
            bugDAO.Dispose();
            usuarioDAO.Dispose();                
            tipoStatusDAO.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

UsuarioDAO code:

```
    private SGSNIModel database;

    public UsuarioDAO()
    {
        database = DatabaseContextHelper.Context;
    }

    public Usuario GetByID(int id, bool asNoTracking = false)
    {
        try
        {
            if (asNoTracking)
                return database.Usuario.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
            else
                return database.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("{0}.{1} -> {2}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message));
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (database != null)
            database.Dispose();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        database.SaveChanges();
    }
```

DatabaseContextHelper code:

```
    private static SGSNIModel _context;

    public static SGSNIModel Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
            {
                _context = new SGSNIModel();
            }

            return _context;
        }
    }
```

I create the Bug object and setting up the propertie "Usuario" to return of UsuarioDAO and the same for "TipoStatus".

When I SaveChanges, the EF duplicate the records in my database. I'm Googled and the suggestion foud is to using one Context, but not work.

Who I can fix this?

Thanks

**[EDIT]**

To solve the issue: pass false for the "asNoTracking", because the object need be tracked.

I.E.

Old code:

```
        Usuario usuario = usuarioDAO.GetByID(1, true);

        TipoStatus tipoStatus = tipoStatusDAO.GetByID(1, true);
```

New code:

```
        Usuario usuario = usuarioDAO.GetByID(1);

        TipoStatus tipoStatus = tipoStatusDAO.GetByID(1);
```

Thanks for Ivan Stoev

Comment: What if you don't pass `true` for `asNoTracking`? You really want the objects that you set as properties of your new `Bug` object to be tracked by the context, i.e. to let context know they are existing.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah, It's work fine! Thanks

Comment: You would better answer you question - this would help other that having the same issue.

Comment: Instead of editing the question with the answer just create a new answer under your question and mark it accordingly. Then its obvious for everyone 1) there is an answer and 2) where to find that answer. Also if others like your answer to your question they can upvote it (so there is that too).